# Connect to an azure iot hub from inside a kubernetes cluster via amqp over websockets

Tags: java, azure, kubernetes, amqp, azure-iot-hub

we are trying to communicate to an azure iothub via amqp over websocket from a java docker container inside an azure kubernetes cluster. Sadly it seems, that the container cant establish a connection while locally or even on another virtual machine (where only docker is installed) the container run successfully.

The network policies rules should allow all necessary protocols and ports to communicate with eventhub endpoint of the iot hub.

Does anybody know which switch we have to pull to "allow" the container from the cluster the communication with the iothub?

The only logs we have are this:

```
13:10:26.688 [main] DEBUG reactor.util.Loggers$LoggerFactory - Using Slf4j logging framework
13:10:26.851 [main] INFO com.azure.messaging.eventhubs.EventHubClientBuilder - connectionId[REDACTED]: Emitting a single connection.
13:10:26.901 [main] DEBUG com.azure.core.amqp.implementation.ReactorConnection - connectionId[REDACTED]: Connection state: UNINITIALIZED
13:10:26.903 [main] INFO com.azure.messaging.eventhubs.implementation.EventHubConnectionProcessor - namespace[REDACTED] entityPath[REDACTED]: Setting next AMQP channel.
13:10:26.903 [main] INFO com.azure.messaging.eventhubs.implementation.EventHubConnectionProcessor - namespace[REDACTED] entityPath[REDACTED]: Next AMQP channel received, updating 0 current subscribers
13:10:26.920 [main] INFO com.azure.core.amqp.implementation.ReactorConnection - connectionId[REDACTED]: Creating and starting connection to REDACTED:443
13:10:26.940 [main] INFO com.azure.core.amqp.implementation.ReactorExecutor - connectionId[REDACTED], message[Starting reactor.]
13:10:26.955 [single-1] INFO com.azure.core.amqp.implementation.handler.ConnectionHandler - onConnectionInit hostname[REDACTED], connectionId[REDACTED]
13:10:26.956 [single-1] INFO com.azure.core.amqp.implementation.handler.ReactorHandler - connectionId[REDACTED] reactor.onReactorInit
13:10:26.956 [single-1] INFO com.azure.core.amqp.implementation.handler.ConnectionHandler - onConnectionLocalOpen hostname[REDACTED:443], connectionId[REDACTED], errorCondition[null], errorDescription[null]
13:10:26.975 [main] DEBUG com.azure.core.amqp.implementation.ReactorSession - Connection state: UNINITIALIZED
13:10:26.991 [main] INFO com.azure.core.amqp.implementation.ReactorConnection - Emitting new response channel. connectionId: REDACTED. entityPath: $management. linkName: mgmt.
13:10:26.991 [main] INFO class com.azure.core.amqp.implementation.RequestResponseChannel<mgmt-session> - namespace[REDACTED] entityPath[$management]: Setting next AMQP channel.
13:10:26.991 [main] INFO class com.azure.core.amqp.implementation.RequestResponseChannel<mgmt-session> - namespace[REDACTED] entityPath[$management]: Next AMQP channel received, updating 0 current subscribers
13:10:26.993 [main] INFO com.azure.messaging.eventhubs.implementation.ManagementChannel - Management endpoint state: UNINITIALIZED
13:10:27.032 [main] INFO com.azure.messaging.eventhubs.implementation.EventHubConnectionProcessor - Upstream connection publisher was completed. Terminating processor.
13:10:27.033 [main] INFO com.azure.messaging.eventhubs.implementation.EventHubConnectionProcessor - namespace[REDACTED] entityPath[REDACTED]: AMQP channel processor completed. Notifying 0 subscribers.
13:10:27.040 [main] INFO com.azure.messaging.eventhubs.implementation.EventHubReactorAmqpConnection - connectionId[REDACTED]: Disposing of connection.
13:10:27.040 [main] INFO class com.azure.core.amqp.implementation.RequestResponseChannel<mgmt-session> - Upstream connection publisher was completed. Terminating processor.
13:10:27.040 [main] INFO class com.azure.core.amqp.implementation.RequestResponseChannel<mgmt-session> - namespace[REDACTED] entityPath[$management]: AMQP channel processor completed. Notifying 0 subscribers.
13:10:27.041 [main] INFO com.azure.core.amqp.implementation.ReactorConnection - connectionId[REDACTED]: Disposing of ReactorConnection.
13:10:27.041 [main] INFO com.azure.messaging.eventhubs.implementation.EventHubConnectionProcessor - namespace[REDACTED] entityPath[REDACTED]: Channel is disposed.
13:10:27.041 [main] INFO com.azure.core.amqp.implementation.ReactorConnection - connectionId[REDACTED]: Removing session 'mgmt-session'
13:10:27.041 [main] INFO com.azure.core.amqp.implementation.ReactorSession - sessionId[mgmt-session]: Disposing of session.
13:10:27.043 [main] INFO com.azure.core.amqp.implementation.AmqpExceptionHandler - Shutdown received: ReactorExecutor.close() was called., isTransient[false], initiatedByClient[true]
13:10:27.089 [single-1] DEBUG com.azure.core.amqp.implementation.handler.SessionHandler - onSessionLocalOpen connectionId[REDACTED], entityName[mgmt-session], condition[Error{condition=null, description='null', info=null}]
13:10:27.090 [single-1] INFO com.azure.core.amqp.implementation.handler.SendLinkHandler - onLinkLocalClose connectionId[REDACTED], linkName[mgmt:sender], errorCondition[null], errorDescription[null]
13:10:27.090 [single-1] INFO com.azure.core.amqp.implementation.handler.ReceiveLinkHandler - onLinkLocalClose connectionId[REDACTED], linkName[mgmt:receiver], errorCondition[null], errorDescription[null]
13:10:27.090 [single-1] DEBUG com.azure.core.amqp.implementation.handler.SessionHandler - onSessionLocalClose connectionId[mgmt-session], entityName[REDACTED], condition[Error{condition=null, description='null', info=null}]
13:10:27.090 [single-1] INFO com.azure.core.amqp.implementation.handler.ConnectionHandler - onConnectionLocalClose hostname[REDACTED:443], connectionId[REDACTED], errorCondition[null], errorDescription[null]
13:10:27.090 [single-1] INFO com.azure.core.amqp.implementation.handler.ConnectionHandler - onConnectionBound hostname[REDACTED], connectionId[REDACTED]
13:10:27.098 [single-1] DEBUG com.azure.core.amqp.implementation.handler.WebSocketsConnectionHandler - connectionId[REDACTED] Adding web sockets transport layer for hostname[REDACTED:443]
13:10:27.125 [single-1] DEBUG com.azure.core.amqp.implementation.handler.DispatchHandler - Running task for event: %s
13:10:27.126 [single-1] INFO com.azure.core.amqp.implementation.ReactorExecutor - connectionId[REDACTED], message[Processing all pending tasks and closing old reactor.]
13:10:27.126 [single-1] DEBUG com.azure.core.amqp.implementation.handler.SendLinkHandler - onLinkLocalOpen connectionId[REDACTED], linkName[mgmt:sender], localTarget[Target{address='$management', durable=NONE, expiryPolicy=SESSION_END, timeout=0, dynamic=false, dynamicNodeProperties=null, capabilities=null}]
13:10:27.126 [single-1] INFO com.azure.core.amqp.implementation.handler.ReceiveLinkHandler - onLinkLocalOpen connectionId[REDACTED], linkName[mgmt:receiver], localSource[Source{address='$management', durable=NONE, expiryPolicy=SESSION_END, timeout=0, dynamic=false, dynamicNodeProperties=null, distributionMode=null, filter=null, defaultOutcome=null, outcomes=null, capabilities=null}]
13:10:27.127 [single-1] INFO com.azure.core.amqp.implementation.ReactorExecutor - connectionId[REDACTED], message[Stopping the reactor because thread was interrupted or the reactor has no more events to process.]
```

Comment: Did you try adding the createOptions in docker container settings? It is used to map the amqp port 5671 to the host virtual machine

Comment: You mentioned "The network policies rules should allow all necessary protocols and ports to communicate with eventhub endpoint of the iot hub." - Can you put some light on it? Please verify in your NSG (network security group) if outbound TCP over port 5671, 5672 are allowed. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-amqp-protocol-guide#amqp-outbound-port-requirements  Since you mentioned the docker container works separately, I assume it's fine at container level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The failure was not the networking at all.

My mistake was, that i assume if i can run the container manual via `docker run -it *` it should also work in a kubernetes cluster. But with the `-it` argument the container stays open und and pseudo-tty was attached. But in the kubernetes cluster this of cause will not happen, so we have to adjust the loop logic of the java application and it works after.

Thanks @ all